# Tic Tac Toe Board - Java

Tags: java

I was trying to write a code for Tic Tac Toe Game. I wrote the following code to display the board of the game but something is wrong and it isn't displaying the required output. Could you please help me figure out where the mistake is?

Here:

**0 represents blank**,

**1 represents X** and

**2 represents O**.

```
public class Trying
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int board[][] = {{1,0,2},
                    {0,1,0},
                    {0,2,0}};

        for(int row = 0; row<3; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col<3; col++)
            {
                printCell(board[row][col]);
                if(col<2)
                {
                    System.out.print(" | ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n------------");
        }
    }

    public static void printCell(int content){
        switch(content){
            case 0: System.out.print(" ");
            case 1: System.out.print("X");
            case 2: System.out.print("O");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Image of the output]

Comment: really sad that you just deleted your c++ question about even numbers. . . Anyways here's your solution: https://pastebin.com/jdTAwaG4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot your `break;`s in your switch statement, try:

```
public static void printCell(int content){
    switch(content){
        case 0: System.out.print(" ");
            break;
        case 1: System.out.print("X");
            break;
        case 2: System.out.print("O");
            break;
    }
}
```

[Read here for why we need `break;`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162574/why-do-we-have-to-use-break-in-switch)

Answer (score 1):

You need a break (and maybe a tabulator character to get the same distance in the signs)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int board[][] = { { 1, 0, 2 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 2, 0 } };

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            printCell(board[row][col]);
            if (col < 2) {
                System.out.print("|");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------");
}

public static void printCell(int content) {
    switch (content) {
        case 0:
            System.out.print("\t \t");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.print("\tX\t");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("\tO\t");
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]